# Switching focus to Jupyter (IPython) terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to place the *focus* from an editor buffer into the IPython terminal using only the keyboard.

I see two approaches, but they both do not seem to work.

1. Shift the focus from the editor to the terminal using `workbench.action.terminal.focusNext` or something alike using `ctrl+backtick`. This seems to be a dead end because all it ever does is shift focus to or activate a terminal in the dedicated terminal buffer at the bottom of all panes.
2. Using `ctrl+{1...n}` to focus on another pane. This works for other editor buffers: I switch the focus to the pane, and the focus goes into the most recent editor buffer. However, this does not work as expected for the IPython terminal: focus does switch to the pane (or group, as it is called in the left vertical side-bar), but does not go into the terminal itself.

This really is unfortunate as in my workflow, I often go forth and back between the editor and the terminal. Of course an alternative is to make a cell in the editor and execute that using `shift+enter`, but that is less interactive that what I would prefer.

My impression is that the IPython terminal for VSCode is something in-between an editor and a terminal, or that the action is caught in between VSCode and the Jupyter server.

Version info:

- Version: 1.32.1 (system setup)
- Commit: 05f146c7a8f7f78e80261aa3b2a2e642586f9eb3
- Date: 2019-03-08T00:51:49.278Z
- Electron: 3.1.3
- Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
- Node.js: 10.2.0
- V8: 6.6.346.32
- OS: Windows_NT x64 6.1.7601

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your talking about the 'Python Interactive' window, I would recommend adding a feature suggestion/bug to our issues list:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues

CTRL + 1/2 should switch the focus to the 'Python Interactive' window, but we don't force the input section to have focus at the moment. That's a bug.

Comment: Yes exactly, the 'Python Interactive' window. Sorry for being unclear about the terminology. Allright, then I'll head over to the issues-list.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution:

--> You might have enabled "auto-save = afterDelay". Change it or disable it.

--> No issues with extentions.

--> In case you are still having issues, it could be your key-bindings. Go to settings and open settings.json (see tutorial on youtube) and remove everything between {}. This will set your VS code to default.

Comment: Please include a YouTube link in your answer rather than suggesting users search there. Or simply delete that text if it is not needed. Thanks.